FPGA Flash Corruption
It seems that I have corrupted the AT25SF081 Flash chip which I am trying to learn about!
I sent it a Write Status Register command from the iceFUN FPGA, and now it seems to be stuck with a specific waveform, unable to be re-programmed out of a certain bitstream.
Using the apio compile commands, it seems that this waveform can be read  no matter what I compile and upload to the FPGA with any of the previous programs that usually resulted in different waveforms.

I also tried to upload new bitstreams using the iceFUN programmer - only to find that it fails at the verification step, with this sort of error:
iceFUNprog example.bin
iceFUN v1, Flash ID 1F 87 01
Erasing sector 000000
Erasing sector 010000
Erasing sector 020000
file size: 135100
Programming ....................................................
Verifying
Verify failed at 000067, 08 expected, 00 read.
make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 1

Again, this error occurs on multiple projects which used to compile and run without issue, so I am quite sure it was the Write Status Register command that has caused this to happen.
Does anyone have some idea about how I might go about understanding the issue more and resetting the flash so that I can reprogram the FPGA again?
EDIT: iceFUNprog man page;
Usage: ./iceFUNprog [-P] <SerialPort>
       ./iceFUNprog <input file>
Options:
  -P <Serial Port>      use the specified USB device [default: /dev/ttyACM0]
  -h                    display this help and exit
  -o <offset in bytes>  start address for write [default: 0]
                        (append 'k' to the argument for size in kilobytes,
                         or 'M' for size in megabytes)
                         or prefix '0x' to the argument for size in hexdecimal
  --help
  -v                    skip verification


What was the original Status Register value, what did you write there, and most importantly, why are you writing Status Register to begin with, what you wanted to achieve?

Originally, all 0's I believe. And I think I wrote all 1's - however the two LSB are dummies so would have stayed at whatever they were at.

I am just experimenting with the chip, as I am quite new to electronics - I thought that this command might make the Page Program functionality available

And said to myself: 'what's the worst that could happen'

From a quick read of the AT25SF081 datasheet writing to the "Write Status Register" is only required to change the write protection status of the flash. Writing non-zero values to bits 7 to 2 in the Write Status Register could have write-protected parts of the address range. Are you able to write 0x00 to the Write Status Register to remove the protection? Not sure if iceFUNprog has an option to do that.

Made an edit to include the iceFUNprog man page - but short answer is that, no, this functionality is not included

It's a SPI flash chip, so your path to recovery probably involves hooking the SPI signals to a SPI master you control (cheap options include Arduino, FTDI, etc) while holding the FPGA in reset so it doesn't try to control the SPI bus.  Then you can send a new Write Status Register command with different contents.

in the future, mess around only with the volatile copy of the Status Register (see section 10.3 in the datasheet), that way a power cycle will recover you to normal operation.
